# Primefaces datatable PF('').filter() doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces datatable search example like that:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

The table doesn't filter and update its values while I'm typing in search field as ajax behavior. Is there anything missing I should include like javascript file or something like that?

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable var="serviceEntity" value="#{serviceSearchMB.allServices}" widgetVar="serviceSearchTable"
            emptyMessage="No services found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{serviceSearchMB.filteredServices}">

        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('serviceSearchTable').filter()"
                        style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
...
```

When I traced the `filter()` function, I found it stops at the following line inside it: `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.handleResponse.call(this,f);`. Do you know why?

Comment: What primefaces and JSF version are you using?

Comment: primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.1.6

Comment: Do you have the filterBy="" on your columns? Are there any JS errors in your browser? Do you have a message element on your xhtml to catch any potential PF errors?

Comment: When I traced the `filter()` function, I found it stops at the following line inside it: `PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.handleResponse.call(this,f);`. Do you know why?

Comment: Thanks for all your cooperation. The problem was due to javascript error.

Comment: @Emil, Thank you very much, although I'm not able to give you "up" for your comment. I don't know why.